# Combinatorics -- Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I need to construct a graph that has the following properties: the vertices of G are the edges of a complete graph $K_5$ on 5 vertices. The vertices of G are adjacent if and only if the corresponding edges of $K_5$ have an endpoint in common. I then need to determine the chromatic number of this graph.

Can someone help me with at least the construction of the graph?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly... you want $vertices$ in $G$ to be $edges$ in $K_5$?

Comment: The construction you describe is called the *line graph* of $K_5$. What part of the construction are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hint: look up line graphs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularGraph.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, where the construction is concerned; it is fairly explicit.  But, let me try to rephrase a little bit, and perhaps that will help.

We start off with $K_5$; to make things precise, let's say that $K_5$ has vertex set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and the edges of $K_5$ are all pairs $\{i,j\}$ where $i,j\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $i\neq j$.

So, the VERTEX set of your new graph should be
$$
V=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}\};
$$
the edge set consists of all pairs $e,f\in V$ such that $e\neq f$ and $e\cap f\neq\varnothing$. So, for instance, there is an edge connecting $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$, but not connecting $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$.

Does that help?

Comment: So every vertex will have an edge in common? Essentially a pentagon with 10 different edges?

Comment: What does the sentence "every vertex will have an edge in common" mean?

Comment: Every vertex will connect to every other vertex by an edge.

Comment: No -- I gave you an example above of two "vertices" in the line graph which are not adjacent: $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. Those two "vertices" (edges in $K_5$) don't have a common endpoint, and so they are not connected in your new graph.

Comment: All right, I think I have the graph created and it's very messy on paper right now. How can I determine the chromatic number now?

Comment: @jerry2144 The same way as you do for any graph! Look for complete subgraphs, consider which vertices are adjacent, etc.